WixToolset V4 Upgrade does not copy files to the same folder as the original install
I have a Wix installer for a Windows Forms application and I am using the WixUI_InstallDir UI set.
WHen installing the application for the first time the user gets an option to select the folder where the application should be installed, the default is ProgramFilesx86 folder, but the user can install to another folder if they wish.
The issue is when the user installs a newer version of the application an run the installer they will not get the option to select folder as it is an upgrade but if the user installed the original version to say c:\OFC_ServiceTool and they run an upgrade the installer uninstalls the orignal and installs the upgrade to the default folder.
I am a novice working with Wix so I have not really tried anything yet as I do not really now where to start ?
This is where I set the UI mode:
        <ui:WixUI Id="CustomWixUI_InstallDir" InstallDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        </ui:WixUI>

And this my folder config:
        <StandardDirectory Id="ProgramFiles6432Folder">
            <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="!(bind.Property.Manufacturer)">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.Property.ProductName)">

This is the Custum UI xml:
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <Fragment>
        <UI Id="CustomWixUI_InstallDir_X86">
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
            <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

            <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
            <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="InstallDir" /> 

            <DialogRef Id="BrowseDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="DiskCostDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
            <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
            <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
            <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
            <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />
            <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="4" Condition="NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID&lt;&gt;&quot;1&quot;" />
            <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath_X86" Order="3" Condition="NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH" />

            <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999" />

            <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg" />

            <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" />
            <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg" Condition="LicenseAccepted = &quot;1&quot; AND NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED" />
            <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomVerifyReadyDlg" Condition="LicenseAccepted = &quot;1&quot; AND WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED" />
            <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Print" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIPrintEula_X86" />

            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg" />
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1" />
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="3" Condition="NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID&lt;&gt;&quot;1&quot;" />
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomVerifyReadyDlg" Order="4" Condition="WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH OR WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID=&quot;1&quot;" />
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath_X86" Order="2" Condition="NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH" />
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1" />
            <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2" />
            <Publish Dialog="CustomVerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg" Order="1" Condition="NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED" />
            <Publish Dialog="CustomVerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg" Order="2" Condition="WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED" />
            <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2" Condition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Repair&quot; OR WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Remove&quot;" />

            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" />

            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" />
            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" />
            <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" />

            <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />
        </UI>

        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
        
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="CustomVerifyReadyDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlg_Title)" TrackDiskSpace="yes">
                <Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="yes" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Hidden="yes" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgInstall)" ShowCondition="NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED AND ALLUSERS" EnableCondition="NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED" DefaultCondition="NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED">
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace &lt;&gt; 1" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;P&quot; OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)" />
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg" Condition="(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;F&quot;)" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="InstallNoShield" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="no" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Hidden="yes" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgInstall)" ShowCondition="NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED AND NOT ALLUSERS" EnableCondition="NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED" DefaultCondition="NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED">
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace &lt;&gt; 1" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;P&quot; OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)" />
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg" Condition="(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;F&quot;)" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Change" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="yes" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Hidden="yes" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgChange)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Change&quot; AND ALLUSERS AND (ADDLOCAL OR REMOVE)" EnableCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Change&quot;" DefaultCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Change&quot;">
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace &lt;&gt; 1" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;P&quot; OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)" />
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg" Condition="(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;F&quot;)" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="ChangeNoShield" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="no" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Hidden="yes" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgChange)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Change&quot; AND (NOT ALLUSERS OR (NOT ADDLOCAL AND NOT REMOVE))" EnableCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Change&quot;" DefaultCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Change&quot;">
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace &lt;&gt; 1" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;P&quot; OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)" />
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg" Condition="(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;F&quot;)" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Repair" Type="PushButton" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Hidden="yes" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgRepair)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Repair&quot;" EnableCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Repair&quot;" DefaultCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Repair&quot;">
                    <Publish Event="ReinstallMode" Value="ecmus" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace &lt;&gt; 1" />
                    <Publish Event="Reinstall" Value="All" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace &lt;&gt; 1" />
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace &lt;&gt; 1" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;P&quot; OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)" />
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg" Condition="(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;F&quot;)" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Remove" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="yes" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Hidden="yes" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgRemove)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Remove&quot; AND ALLUSERS" EnableCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Remove&quot;">
                    <Publish Event="Remove" Value="All" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace &lt;&gt; 1" />
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace &lt;&gt; 1" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;P&quot; OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)" />
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg" Condition="(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;F&quot;)" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="RemoveNoShield" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="no" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Hidden="yes" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgRemove)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Remove&quot; AND NOT ALLUSERS" EnableCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Remove&quot;">
                    <Publish Event="Remove" Value="All" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace &lt;&gt; 1" />
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace &lt;&gt; 1" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;P&quot; OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)" />
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg" Condition="(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;F&quot;)" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Update" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="yes" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Hidden="yes" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgUpdate)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Update&quot; OR WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED AND ALLUSERS" EnableCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Update&quot; OR WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED">
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace &lt;&gt; 1" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;P&quot; OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)" />
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg" Condition="(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;F&quot;)" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="UpdateNoShield" Type="PushButton" ElevationShield="no" X="212" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Hidden="yes" Disabled="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgUpdate)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Update&quot; OR WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED AND NOT ALLUSERS" EnableCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Update&quot; OR WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED">
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace &lt;&gt; 1" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;P&quot; OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)" />
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False" Condition="OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;D&quot;" />
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg" Condition="(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST=&quot;F&quot;)" />
                </Control>

                <Control Id="InstallTitle" Type="Text" X="15" Y="15" Width="300" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgInstallTitle)" ShowCondition="NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED" HideCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Repair&quot; OR WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Remove&quot;"/>
                <Control Id="InstallText" Type="Text" X="25" Y="70" Width="320" Height="80" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgInstallText)" ShowCondition="NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED" HideCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Repair&quot; OR WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Remove&quot;"/>
                <Control Id="ChangeTitle" Type="Text" X="15" Y="15" Width="300" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgChangeTitle)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Change&quot;" />
                <Control Id="ChangeText" Type="Text" X="25" Y="70" Width="320" Height="80" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgChangeText)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Change&quot;" />
                <Control Id="RepairTitle" Type="Text" X="15" Y="15" Width="300" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgRepairTitle)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Repair&quot;" />
                <Control Id="RepairText" Type="Text" X="25" Y="70" Width="320" Height="80" Hidden="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgRepairText)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Repair&quot;" />
                <Control Id="RemoveTitle" Type="Text" X="15" Y="15" Width="300" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgRemoveTitle)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Remove&quot;" />
                <Control Id="RemoveText" Type="Text" X="25" Y="70" Width="320" Height="80" Hidden="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgRemoveText)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Remove&quot;" />
                <Control Id="UpdateTitle" Type="Text" X="15" Y="15" Width="300" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Hidden="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgUpdateTitle)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Update&quot; OR WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED " />
                <Control Id="UpdateText" Type="Text" X="25" Y="70" Width="320" Height="80" Hidden="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgUpdateText)" ShowCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Update&quot; OR WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED " />

                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg" />
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="156" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" DefaultCondition="WixUI_InstallMode = &quot;Remove&quot;" />
                <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.VerifyReadyDlgBannerBitmap)" />
                <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>

</Wix>


I actually found a soultion to this while waiting for my question to be published.

This can be solved by adding the installfolder to the registry and creating a property that hold that value.
Like this:
Somewhere in a fragment add this:
<RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" Name="InstallDir" />

Then before initialization of the UI add this:
    <Property Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <RegistrySearch Id="InstallFolderRegKey" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Name="InstallDir" Type="raw"/>
</Property>

In this case INSTALLFOLDER is also the id of the folder where all components reside:
<StandardDirectory Id="ProgramFiles6432Folder">
    <Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="!(bind.Property.Manufacturer)">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.Property.ProductName)">

And also what I put in to wix UI:
<ui:WixUI Id="CustomWixUI_InstallDir" InstallDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER">
</ui:WixUI>

